# Can a rake task know about the other tasks in the invocation chain?

Tags: ruby, build-process, rake, rakefile

Rake (like make) is able to have many targets/tasks specified on invocation. Is it possible for a rake task to access the list of tasks the user invoked, in order to do its job?

Scenario:

Consider a Rake-based build tool. A help task would like to know what tasks were also specified in order to print their usage and halt the build process. The benefit of this as opposed to rake-style parameter passing are cleaner syntax (`rake help build` instead of `rake help task=build`) and chaining (`rake help build run_tests` would print usage for both).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can, by accessing `Rake.application.top_level_tasks` and examining the collection that's returned.